# GitHub Pages What to write in custom domain?

Tags: github, github-pages, github-pages-deploy-action

Custom domain
[image]
custom domains allow you to serve your site from a domain other than akshitmodhiya.github.io.

what to write in it as "https://akshitmodhiya.github.io/xypo" not working

Answer (score 0):

To use Custom Domain in Github Pages. You need to own your own domain name.

In order to use `/xypo` in your github domain . Create a folder named `xypo` in your repository and place all the web files there.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you haven't built and deployed your application on GitHub Pages yet.

After you do that, a section stating, "Your site is live at [https://akshitmodhiya.github.io/xypo"](https://akshitmodhiya.github.io/xypo%22) appears under "GitHub Pages".

After deployment to GitHub Pages, you need to:

**Step 1** - purchase a domain, *akshitmodhiya.com* from GoDaddy for example.

**Step 2** - configure new domain's DNS settings in GoDaddy.

**Step 3** - add 5 records. They are as follows: [DNS records configuration setting screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51X25.png)

**Step 4** - wait between 5 minutes and 24 hours while the DNS settings take effect.

**Step 5** - come back to your GitHub repo's GitHub Pages section, add *akshitmodhiya.com* as Custom domain and click on Save.

**Step 6** - look up under GitHub Pages and notice now it states, "Your site is live at https://akshitmodhiya.com".

**Step 7** (Bonus) - Every time you make changes to repo, re-build and re-deploy the application, the live site URL will reset to https://akshitmodhiya.github.io/xypo. To fix this, you need to enter akshitmodhiya.com in Custom domain and click Save, every time.

And there you go, your application Xypo has its own custom domain.

I haven't found a permanent solution to the issue mentioned in Step 7, yet.
When I do, I will update my answer here.

Reference:

- [GitHub Docs - Managing a custom domain for your GitHub Pages site](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site)